# Can't call numba functions from inside njit'ed functions

Tags: python, numpy, types, numba

Working with `numba`, I stumbled upon very unexpected behavior. I created an `nb.njit` function inside of which I was trying to create a `nb.typed.List` of `int8 numpy` arrays, so I tried to create a corresponding `numba` type.

```
nb.int8[:]  # type of the list elements
```

So, I set this type to an `nb.typed.List` via `lsttype` keyword.

```
l = nb.typed.List(lsttype=nb.int8[:])  # list of int8 numpy ndarrays
```

What I got is:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> getitem(class(int8), slice<a:b>)
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
   - Of which 16 did not match due to:
   Overload in function 'getitem': File: <built-in>: Line <N/A>.
     With argument(s): '(class(int8), slice<a:b>)':
    No match.
```

Which, I suppose, means that `numba` is trying to slice the `nb.int8` type object, as if it doesn't understand the notation.

So, I tried it the other way, creating an empty array of `np.int8` type, and using the `nb.typeof` function.

```
nb.typeof(np.array([], dtype=np.int8))
```

And it returned:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'typeof' of type Module(<module 'numba' from '/Users/.../venv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/__init__.py'>)
```

This I do not understand! How can `numba` not see **itself**?

The minimum example is very simple:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def v():
    print(nb.typeof(np.array([], dtype=np.int8)))

v()
```

So I tried using the same function, but without the `@nb.njit`.

**AND IT PRINTS!**

```
array(int8, 1d, C)
```

Also, I tried importing numba inside the function, since it doesn't see the module, but it produced:

```
numba.core.errors.UnsupportedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing                    bytecode)
Use of unsupported opcode (IMPORT_NAME) found
```

I tried reinstalling and updating both `numba` and `numpy`, also.

**What kind of trickery is that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a nasty workaround.

```
@nb.njit
def f(types=(nb.int8[::1], nb.float64[::1])):
    a = nb.typed.List.empty_list(types[0])
    b = nb.typed.List.empty_list(types[1])
    # and so on...
```

`[::1]` means a 1-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` of C-type.

Comment: but the question is still open. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm also curious as I've just run into this issue. I've posted a link [here](https://numba.discourse.group/t/numba-types-inside-nopython-functions/511) as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about letting numba figure the type out by itself?

```
@nb.njit
def v():
    l=nb.typed.List()
    l.append(np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int8))
    return l
v()
```

Returns `ListType[array(int8, 1d, C)]([[1 2 3]])` for me